# android studio add .aar dependency for module without generating other .gradle files

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

I'm working on a part of a huge android application from eclipse, and converting this part into a package containing only one build.gradle file.

**I have done:**

1.add all dependency descriptions in build.gradle(.jar/.arr), all the libraries located in the remote maven repository.

2.import eclipse project into android studio, and build the gradle.

**I have seen:**

1. gradle built succeeded, seen all *.jar in the External Library.
2. no *.arr in External Library after successful building.(I tried to only compile *.aar library in an empty application project, *.arr was generated in app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar...,but coming with some build errors which are not see in the mentioned project)

**Problems:**

1. no .arr in the current Android Module(Project->External Libraries)
2. if I click **File->New->New Module->import .arr/.jar libraries**, there will be another build.gradle file and make this module an application project.

The reason why I try this so hard to keep this as a Android Module is that the online compiling(packaging) system requires a specific file structure to package all of this part correctly.

Sorry for a long question, could someone give me a little advice?

build.gradle:

> compile 'com.xxx.android:xxx:1.0.2.2@aar'

gradle build errors when only building *.arr:

Error:(1) Attribute "layout" has already been defined
Error:(12, 26)    No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_width' with    value '@dimen/uik_progressSize').
Error:(13, 27) No resource found    that matches the given name (at 'layout_height' with value    '@dimen/uik_progressSize').

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':..:MyProject:MyProject')
}
```

settings.gradle

```
include '..:MyProject:MyProject'
```